# Solve a specific number with expressions like (e/e+e/e) with no digits

Tags: programming

So this is only for fun really. I'm trying to solve a number with expressions like `e/e = 1`. This could work for any number really, but I'm trying to solve it only using expressions.

I want to do this using programming. Could be Javascript, Python, etc. I assume brute forcing my way is the best way to do this? Basically I want something like this:

```
Solve 4000
e/e = 1
(e/e + e/e) = 2
(e/e + e/e)^(e/e + e/e) = 4
(e/e + e/e)^(e/e + e/e + e/e + e/e) = 16
```

So "just like that" we have 16. If we then do:

```
((e/e + e/e)^(e/e + e/e + e/e + e/e))^(e/e + e/e + e/e)
```

We have 4096. If we then do:

```
((e/e + e/e)^(e/e + e/e + e/e + e/e))^(e/e + e/e + e/e) - ((e/e + e/e)^(e/e + e/e + e/e) * ((e/e + e/e + e/e) * (e/e + e/e + e/e + e/e))
```

We have.. tadaa, 4000. Basically I just extracted 96 from 4096 by doing `4096 - (12*8)`. Elegant? No. Fun? Extremely. Would doing this through brute force be possible? Remember, not a single digit was used.

Comment: $e$ is a number. Do you mean not a digit was used?

Comment: @Momo Sorry, my bad. Yes, not a single digit was used.